# std::condition_variable between processes using shared memory

Tags: c++, shared-memory, condition-variable

I am trying to use `std::condition_variable` (with `std::mutex`) to do some inter process synchronization.
I am putting both the `cv` and `mutex` in the shared memory to achieve this, which should be possible.
All is good with a number of processes locking the `mutex` and calling wait on the `cv`.
When another process finally calls `cv.notify_one/notify_all` it ends up crashing with a SIGSEV.

I have tried the same with `pthread_cond_t` as well with the same result.
Is this absolutely not possible?

I am able to achieve the synchronization using Named Semaphores ( `sem_t` ), which underneath does very similar thing by using a shared memory.

Kindly Advice.

4 processes share CV, Mutex an integer and a bool via shared memory.
I have 3 processes each calling wait on the CV, and a fourth process that calls notify_all.
I expect the first 3 process to come out of wait.
I am seeing the 4th process crash the moment notify_all is called.

Comment: I am pretty sure all `std` synchronization primitives are only built to work between threads, and not between processes. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: fordcars - I can see that, and technically I am using it between multiple threads that happen to be across processes instead of being intra process. My question is when I can use regular data/variable as shared between processes using shared memory what is stopping the std or pthread variables from being shared.